# Upgrade to typescript 2.2.0 causes error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'angular'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript2.0

I have an angular 1.5 project that I'm slowly converting to typescript.  I have NOT committed to modules yet, I just import interfaces from other files, which doesn't create modules.  I have a number of typescript files now, and the project has been compiling fine with typescript version 2.1.5.  After I upgrade just my npm typescript package to 2.2.0 or 2.2.1, then I get error from tsc, "error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'angular'" on some lines using "angular.". I am executing tsc directly using the command line.

I have tried adding "moduleResolution": "Node" to my tsconfig, didn't work.
I can get the build to work using `import * as angular from "../../../node_modules/@types/angular/index";`, however, then I get run time errors because modules have been created, which our project doesn't support yet.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "listFiles": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "js/app"
  },
  "include": [ "app/**/*", "@types/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Imagine.UI.NG",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.6.7",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.9",
    "@types/angular-ui-bootstrap": "^0.13.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
     ....
    "typescript": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-breadcrumb": "^0.5.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.4.2",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-trx-reporter": "^0.2.9"
  }
}
```

Sample code that fails with "error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'angular'" on the line `public $http: angular.IHttpService`.  It doesn't complain about `angular.module`.

```
import { IImagineSettings } from "../../app.config";

class AboutCtrl {
    SiteVersion: string;
    ApiVersion: string;

    static $inject = ["imagineSettings", "$http", "$translate"];
    constructor(public imagineSettings: IImagineSettings, public $http: angular.IHttpService, public $translate: any) {
        let fake = "do something";
    }
}

angular.module("Imagine.UI.NG")
    .component("about",
    {
        templateUrl: "app/partial/about/about.html",
        bindings: {},
        controller: AboutCtrl
    });
```

Comment: So? Lets see the errors then

Comment: The error is "error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'angular'" on the constructor line.  I'll clarify in my question as well.